# Was ist ein "versprengter Soldat"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich habe im Internet nach diesem Wort gesucht und habe verstanden, dass ein versprengter Soldat ein Soldat ist, der von seiner Einheit oder Truppe getrennt wurde.
Ich habe aber nicht verstanden, warum er versprengt wurde, heißt das, dass er was falsch gemacht hat? Gibt es eine Bestrafung für ihn? Kann er wieder in der Armee dienen?

Answer (score 11):

Versprengt ist nichts, womit ein Soldat "bestraft" wird.

Das Wort "versprengen" bedeutet:

> **einen Verband, besonders eine militärische Einheit, versprengen**
> einen Verband, besonders eine militärische Einheit, auseinandertreiben, in die Flucht schlagen, zerstreuen

Inzwischen wird aber nicht nur das aktive in die Flucht treiben durch einen Feind hierdurch ausgedrückt.
Es bedeutet schlicht: Der Soldat wurde -durch äußere Umstände- von seiner Einheit getrennt. Er kann sich jederzeit wieder mit seiner Einheit verbinden, wenn er sie denn wieder findet....

Die genaue Wortdefinition kannst Du [hier bei DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/versprengen) nachlesen

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort *versprengen* ist zusammengesetzt aus dem Präfix *ver-* und dem Verb *sprengen*.

Das Präfix *ver-* kann mehrere Bedeutungen haben, hier bedeutet es die Bewegung eines Objekts in eine unbestimmte Richtung (wie auch in *verlaufen, verfahren, vertreiben*)

Das Verb *sprengen* bedeutete ursprünglich *(jemanden) springen machen* und wird in drei verschiedenen Bedeutungen verwendet:

- galoppieren

  > Der Reiter **sprengte** das Pferd. = Der Reiter brachte das Pferd zum galoppieren.

  In dieser transitiven Konstruktion wird das Verb heute aber nicht mehr verwendet. Es leben aber diese Konstruktionen weiter:

  > Die Pferde **sprengten** freudig über die Weide.
  > Der Reiter **sprengte** auf seinem Ross davon.
- eine Flüssigkeit verspritzen, Flüssigkeit auf etwas sprühen

  > Vor dem Bügeln empfiehlt es sich, ein wenig Wasser auf die Wäsche zu **sprengen.**
  > Bei Wasserknappheit ist es verboten, den Rasen zu **sprengen.**

  Der Weihwasserwedel, mit dem ein Priester die Gläubigen mit geweihtem Wasser besprengt, heißt demzufolge *»**Sprengel**«,* und davon abgeleitet hieß auch der kirchliche Amtsbezirk eines Bischofs *»Sprengel«.* Der Sprengel war also nicht nur ein nasser Wedel, sondern auch der Bezirk, innerhalb dessen der Bischof mit seinem Wedel Weihwasser versprengen durfte. Später wurde diese Bezeichnung für einen Amtsbezirk auch in die weltliche Administration übernommen und existiert heute bei politischen Wahlen als Name für die kleinsten Zählbezirke weiter.

  Früher wurden nicht nur Flüssigkeiten, sondern im übertragenen Sinn auch Nachrichten, hauptsächlich aber Lügen und Gerüchte ausgesprengt (verbreitet).
- etwas rasch und gewaltsam auseinandertreiben

  > Die plötzlich aus dem Hinterhalt angreifenden Soldaten **sprengten** die gegnerische Truppe auseinander.
  > Der laute Knall **versprengte** eine Schar Krähen.

  Seit dem 17. Jahrhundert beschreibt man mit dem Wort *»**sprengen**«* auch das Zerstören von Gegenständen durch Auseinandertreiben mit Hilfe von *Spreng*stoffen. Damit sind meist Explosivstoffe gemeint, aber nicht ausschließlich:

  > Der alte Schornsteim muss **gesprengt** werden.
  > Gefrierendes Wasser **sprengt** die Felsen.

---

Wenn Soldaten versprengt werden, bedeutet das also, dass sie durch eine äußere Einwirkung von ihrer Gruppe getrennt werden. Oft löst sich dadurch die ganze Gruppe auf. Es kann aber auch passieren, dass nur einzelne Soldaten versprengt werden und die Mehrheit der Soldaten weiterhin zusammen bleibt.

Zur Bedeutung von *versprengt sein* gehört immer auch dazu, dass das ungewollt geschieht. In den meisten Fällen wird eine Gruppe durch einen Angriff von Feinden (oder auch von wilden Tieren) versprengt. Das ist aber nicht zwingend notwendig:

> Ein Trupp Soldaten durchquerte in einer finsteren Neumondnacht den dichten Wald. Die Mannen verloren den Kontakt zueinander und wurden durch ihre eigene Schuld und ohne Feindeinwirkung in alle Himmelsrichtungen versprengt.